# Is the North Indian custom of the bride kicking over a pot of rice on first entering the in-laws' house based on scripture?

Tags: culture, marriage, customs

I believe the rice getting scattered over the house represents the bride filling her new home with prosperity.  Does any scripture prescribe/describe this custom?

Comment: Seems to be the same kind of ritual as rice pouring on each other in South Indian weddings.

Comment: they don't "pour" akshata - elders sprikle it on younger folk to bless them.